# Best practices for framing a hierarchy of views

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

From other stack overflow questions, I understand that in your view controller, you can use the **viewDidLoad** method to initialize subviews and the **viewWillLayoutSubviews** method to set the frames. This implies that we need to keep a reference of all the views within the view controller instance (as below). This is all fine and great and handles device rotations, etc.

```
UILabel* myLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [myLabel setText:@"Hello"];
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [myLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 21)];
}
```

My question is what if you have a complex hierarchy of subviews. For example, what if you have a subview which is a UIView and you add subviews to that UIView (and potentially it even goes deeper). Do you have to keep a reference to every view in this whole view hierarchy so that on **viewWillLayoutSubviews**, you can modify the frame of each view? This seems like the only way. Are constraints the best way so that you don't have to modify frames as often? Is the best answer to build tons of custom UIViews to make managing this hierarchy more manageable and self-contained within each custom view?

Hopefully this is a clear enough question..thanks in advance.

Comment: If your logic is that complicated, why don't you just use a .xib file to do all of it for you?

Comment: I've only used IB and done things programmatically, so I haven't messed around with the .xib files much manually. FYI, the views I'm talking about are dynamically fetched from the server, there could be 1 or 100 of them and they could all look a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you manipulate a view or subview, in a way that could change the layout constraints, you have to call

```
[view layoutSubviews];
```

this will remake the constraints with the new property settings. When the viewController is loaded, you would set all properties not dealing with the frame or bounds and then with in the viewWillLayoutSubviews you set the frames of the views this is so all the constraints are made and ensured that they are met.

Any object you put in the storyboard that you want to use, should have a property this will hold a reference to that object. This is a good coding practice, especially if you follow the rules of test driven development.

Now to answer your questions, if you create the complex hierarchy in the storyboard then everything should be fine as long as your constraints are fine, if you make it in code just be sure to call layoutSubviews **when ever you call addSubview**
Example:

```
UIView* view1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
UIView* view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[view1 addSubview:view2];
[view1 layoutSubviews];
```

More views does not make the structure better, but if you have 100 subviews... lets be real.. something needs to be categorized in a separate view..

Constraints let you define the frames of views perfectly. You might not notice the differences at first, but if you compare it to Autoresizing Mask then you will see the differences. Also, here is a guide that blatantly shows you the differences.

[LayoutConstraints and Autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm creating these subviews in code (maybe I should create them in storyboard, not sure). So you are implying that I need to have a reference to every view in the hierarchy if I manage this without the storyboard?

Comment: it would help make your code more descriptive to put a label to them, I sometimes go as far as making an entirely new subclass of UIView to handle different sections of 1 scene, but that is situational, in the end if your code is easy to read and not complex then you did a good job

Comment: It just seems a bit much to keep a reference of every subview's subview...and all their subviews, etc (recursive).

Comment: You don't have to do every view, i often skip views that are just there for storing objects, but at the same time i have had a scroll view with a view for it's content and then 5 views in that and all of those had references, along with most of their subviews, if it doesn't need to be manipulated with code, then don't worry about it

Comment: The main thing I want to do is re-frame everything upon rotation in the correct way. A lot of it is probably do-able without frames (like programming some constraints) but I was having trouble getting used to constraints as well. Overall, I'm just a newbie trying to figure out the best practices.

Comment: And also with so much dynamic content (built from data coming in from the server), I'm hesitant to spend too much time using the storyboard. Maybe I'm wrong and there's some elegant way to use the storyboard a lot, even with dynamic content. Do you have any advice there?

Comment: using the storyboard gets rid of all the allocation boiler code, but the data like label text, is still going to be in code, personally i think you should use a storyboard, for a visual representation, also you can visibly see where it is... sometimes i type numbers wrong and i think i'm write... but that wont be as obvious in text as it would be in a storyboard of incorrect width/height/origins

Answer (score 1):

Also worth considering is using child view controllers if you wish to compartmentalize some of the logic and reuse components.